# Difference between logistic regression predictions

Tags: probability, logistic, tensorflow

I have created two logits using tensorflow for a binary classification problem. The first one is built on one feature "Dose", the second one is built on two features "Dose" & "LogP". Now I am testing these models using a set of 311 molecules. I am getting better AUC on the model built on two features. I want to know which of the molecules went through the biggest change? Should I subtract the probabilities that I received during predictions or should I first take the log of the probabilities and then subtract them? or anything else? Thanks.

Comment: By "which of the molecules went through the biggest change", could you please tell me its meaning? Do you mean which kind of molecules would most probably be in a particular class?

Comment: What I meant by the biggest change is the molecules that were not correctly predicted using one feature model are now predicted correctly with two feature model.

Comment: So can I understand it as you want to know the effect of the additional feature on the molecule classification?

Comment: Yes pretty much

Comment: It seems strange to me to predict using only one feature and that feature is the "dose".. Anyway, you want to know the change.

Comment: Well, I gave it as an example, the real sets that I have are made up of 4 and 10 features respectively.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76578/discussion-between-rohitf-and-lerner).

Comment: I wonder if principal component analysis would better fit your issue